# как сделать цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Как сделать цикл из этого:
`order = myapi.OrderInfo(order_id=p)` - это запрос возвращающий ответ

```
{'success': 1, 'return': {'334259581': {'pair': 'usd_rur', 'type': 'buy', 'start_amount': 1.0, 'amount': 1.0, 'rate': 59.57292, 'timestamp_created': 1528810265, 'status': 0}}}
```

Интересует `'status'` который принимает значение 
status:

- 0 - активен
- 1 - исполненный ордер
- 2 - отмененный
- 3 - отмененный или был частично исполнен.

В сторону какого цикла лучше смотреть, **for** or **while**,
чтобы он (цикл) перебирал или получал ответ выводил (print'ом) сравнивал и над нужным делал нужное?

Comment: В return может быть несколько значений?

Comment: что значит несколько? интересует ответ "status' и значение '334259581' со временем менятся

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если мы не знаем по какому ключу хранятся данные, то можно представить их в другом виде, например как список:

```
rs = {'success': 1, 'return': {'334259581': {'pair': 'usd_rur', 'type': 'buy', 'start_amount': 1.0, 'amount': 1.0, 'rate': 59.57292, 'timestamp_created': 1528810265, 'status': 0}}}

# Вытаскиваем первое значение из списка
value = list(rs['return'].values())[0]
print(value)
print(value['status'])
```

Результат:

```
{'pair': 'usd_rur', 'type': 'buy', 'start_amount': 1.0, 'amount': 1.0, 'rate': 59.57292, 'timestamp_created': 1528810265, 'status': 0}
0
```

---

Или получить список ключей словаря и по первому ключу получить данные:

```
key = list(rs['return'].keys())[0]
print(key)

value = rs['return'][key]
print(value)
print(value['status'])
```

Результат:

```
334259581
{'pair': 'usd_rur', 'type': 'buy', 'start_amount': 1.0, 'amount': 1.0, 'rate': 59.57292, 'timestamp_created': 1528810265, 'status': 0}
0
```

---

Если нужно в цикле обработать, тогда:

```
for key, value in rs['return'].items():
    status = value['status']
    print('key: {}, status: {}'.format(key, status))
```

Результат:

```
key: 334259581, status: 0
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78826/discussion-on-answer-by-gil9red---).